# Language to have android phone reboot when there is a certain amount of failed password attempts

Tags: java, android, powermanager

I am trying to have Android Phone (LP 5.1.1) reboot when there is a certain amount of failed screen passwords.  Here is my language in Keyguard:

```
if (mLockPatternUtils.isSeparateEncryptionPasswordEnabled() && failedAttempts >= 5) {
        final PowerManager powerManager = mContext.getSystemService(PowerManager.class);
        powerManager.reboot(null);
```

I get a compile error:

```
frameworks/base/packages/Keyguard/src/com/android/keyguard/KeyguardSecurityContainer.java:409:
```

error: method getSystemService in class Context cannot be applied to given types;
final PowerManager powerManager = mContext.getSystemService(PowerManager.class);
                                                      ^
required: String

found: Class

reason: actual argument Class cannot be converted to

String by method invocation conversion

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of PowerManager.class can you use Context.POWER_SERVICE?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the PowerManager.class, I'd go with `Context.POWER_SERVICE`

Or maybe just:

```
    if (mLockPatternUtils.isSeparateEncryptionPasswordEnabled() &&vfailedAttempts >= 5) { 
           final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
           powerManager.reboot(null);
    }
```

You have to add Context to your imports.

Of course if your target phones are ROOTED:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","reboot now"});
```

would suffice.

Comment: Trying to compile now. Interestingly, this was cherry picked from Android MM commit where it worked, but not in LP...

Comment: That's strange. Your code above looks fine though, you should be able to use PowerManager.class as well as Context.POWER_SERVICE or so I'd thought. Why are you using LP, if I may inquire? Is it the latest version for your device?

Comment: This time it tells me: incompatible types
           final PowerManager powerManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); required: PowerManager
  found:    Object

Comment: LP. I have a Sony device and camera is of very low quality in MM

Comment: I think your mContext may be not pointing to the right thing.Try: getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

Comment: final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); You may need to cast it to (PowerManager) type.

Comment: Now, with your last suggestion, it is continuing to compile without errors. It is going to take a while to finish and check if the phone shuts down, but so far, so good... Thanks a bunch...

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. You have answered my question.

Comment: i'll change my answer to reflect it. Please upvote and accept answer if you will! Thanks.